# Condtionally load scripts in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I can load (enqueue a script in wordpress by using this in my child theme functions.php file:

```
function my_assets() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'about', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/about.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0' , true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_assets' );
```

The loading isn't an issue, the script works, but when I want to conditionally load it up on a page it doesn't work with this code (in the same file and directly below the above code):

```
function deregister_about_javascript() {
    if ( !is_page(490) ) {
        wp_dequeue_script( 'about' );
    }
}
```

The script still appears on all pages. I tried using the name of the page, the slug, I changed wp_dequeue_script to admin_dequeue_script and nothing works.

Of note though, when I click on the **page** to obtain the page ID number whilst in admin, it has the word "post" in the address bar, even though I am in "Pages". *wp-admin/**post**.php?**post**=490&action=edit*

lol It seems so straight forward, what am I missing?

Thank you

Comment: How/where are you calling the `deregister_about_javascript()` function? I understand you've placed the function declaration in the same file but how are you actually calling that function?

Comment: @Andy I thought about that previously lol and I'm not. The code where I "enqueue" the script works without being called so I figured it must be the same thing. I was wrong?

Comment: The first function is called because you've added it to the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action, so when WordPress fires that action it calls your function. I've posted an answer anyway and it gets rid of the need for a second function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of executing another function to dequeue the script, you could just return early and not enqueue the script in the first place based on a certain condition:

```
function my_assets() {
    if ( ! is_page( 490 ) ) {
        return;
    }

    wp_enqueue_script( 'about', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/about.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_assets' );
```

Now the `wp_enqueue_script` function only gets called on page ID 490.

Comment: lol I honestly feel like a complete retard honestly, I didn't call any actions. I like your answer as it makes it more efficient also :) thank you so much